# unbind hover inside a .everytime

Tags: jquery

Im having a issue within a hover that is inside a  .everytime(2000)...

```
j("#ifr").everyTime(2000,function(){...
j.ajax({
 url: "script.php",
 cache: true,
 success: function(html){

j(".chatline").hover(function(){
var did = j(this).attr('rel');
j("#status-"+did+":hidden").fadeIn('fast');
...}
```

the problem is that when .everytime fires the .hover refires and then it blinks because its has hidden class. Tried unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(function){... but no change.

Is there any way of solving this ?

Comment: Maybe you should also explain what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: When hover it should show a hidden div. thought the code would tell this :p

Comment: But why do you repeatedly bind the hover handler in the Ajax success callback?

Comment: I cannot seem to get j(".chatline") from outside the success callback :/

Comment: Where/what is the `".chatline"` element?

Comment: .chatline :<div id='cht-".$id."' rel='".$id."' class='".$first." chatdivsjef".$linecol." chatline chatdiv".$linecol." ".$fadeOut." rc3'>

Comment: when i hover a .chatline it hits div id cht-xx and fires the div with id status-xx to fadeIn(fast).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:none` to whatever you are hiding since it sounds like your div isn't initially hidden and that is why you are seeing the blinking.

**EDIT**

Instead of rebinding everytime in the success callback why not use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind.  This will handle the case when new HTML is added to the DOM.

```
j(".chatline").live('mouseover mouseout', function(){
var did = j(this).attr('rel');
j("#status-"+did+":hidden").fadeIn('fast');
...
});

j("#ifr").everyTime(2000,function(){...
j.ajax({
 url: "script.php",
 cache: true,
 success: function(html){ 
             ... 
});
```

Comment: the hidden class is defined in css as display:none , so it has no effect changing to display:none straight into the div style.

Comment: it must be blinking because its hidden, and when i hover it when .everytime fires it fadeIn again. that's what i want to get rid of :)

Comment: Hmm...why doesnt anyone reply when its not a brand new thread? :s

Comment: @Thundercat - If there is no new activity some people will think the question is dead.

Comment: thank you amurra :) Will test your edit in a sec.. Much appreciated!